# if array values exist in a string (similar to regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

How can I determine if a string contains one of the values from an array?

For example:

```
var a = ["abc","def","ghi"];

var s = "jskljfdkljflkjk abc jskfdjklsj";


for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(/a[i]/.test(s)) alert(1);
}
```

This obviously doens't work... I know it's very possible though hahaha

Comment: Do you want to match stuff like "ABC" in "jskljfdABCkljflkjk"?

Comment: thanks everyone! looks like i have a few different methods to choose from :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for creating the regular expression is incorrect. That regex will only return true for a string "ai". And you're testing the regular expression against the array. I think what you meant to write is:

```
if(RegExp(a[i]).test(s)) alert(1);
```

You would probably be better off just using indexOf in this case. It'll be faster and you won't need to escape any characters.

```
var a = ["abc","def","ghi"],
    s = "jskljfdkljflkjk abc jskfdjklsj";

for(var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++)
    if(s.indexOf(a[i])+1) alert('string s contains a value from array a');
```

Comment: no need to create a host object with new here. Also, I think `~` has better perfs than `+1` (will try)

Comment: Thanks! also great explanation too!!

Comment: @user1737909 you're right. I've removed the 'new' declaration from the regex.

Comment: @user1737909 seems like they are virtually the same in performance for all modern browsers ( [test results](http://jsperf.com/indexof-plusone-vs-tilde) )

Answer (score 1):

```
function doesStringContainElementFromArray(str, arr)
{
  for ( var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  {
    if ( str.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1 )
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "RegExp" function/constructor (if you really need regexps)

```
if (RegExp(a[i]).test(a)) {
  alert(1);
}
```

if you don't, just use `.indexOf`

```
if (s.indexOf(a[i]) != -1) {
  alert("a[i]="+a[i]+" is matched in " + s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't need regex and just want to match strings?

Comment: yea thanks just realized as you answered. Mainly interested in your regex answer, but thanks alot!!

Comment: I think regexp is much slower than indexOf

Answer (score 1):

You can use search method of JavaScript

```
var a = ["abc","def","ghi"];

var s  = "jskljfdkljflkjk abc jskfdjklsj";

for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){

  if(s.search( a[i] ) != -1)
  {
     alert("found");
  }
}
```